# Some simple socket questions for C++

Tags: c++, sockets

I've done a fair amount of coding in C++, and I'm looking into sockets. Can I listen to a socket on another computer on my network if there's no client program running on it? I would use this to listen to the HTTP port.

Comment: "if there's no client program running on it" -> the nb of clients doesn't matters. The only important thing is that apache (or other web server) listen the port 80 for clients. You will be able to see only the first site defined by the user (/var/www/ generally).

Comment: This is a language-independent question.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking about sniffing network traffic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the program that listens on the socket must be running on the computer where you want to listen on. You could use a tool like `ssh` to log in to the other computer and launch your program there - but your program would have to be copied to the other computer first.

Well, you can kind of fake it with firewall rules to redirect traffic to your machine and back again, but the real socket is always on the computer that is running the program.

Comment: So the program on the other computer would also forward the traffic to my computer as well, correct?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. Are you talking about the firewall rules? At least on Linux, those are implemented by the operating system (kernel) itself, not by a program.

Comment: No, I'm not going to mess with the firewall.

Comment: Well that's all I was talking about when I was talking about forwarding the traffic. But actually, you could use a program to forward traffic instead of a firewall. Such a program is known as a _proxy_.